# Where should I put PHP code for a HTML form?

Tags: php, html

I can't seem to find an answer to this particular question, so I apologize if it's already been answered and I have yet to see it.

I have a HTML form that takes visitors name, e-mail, and a message; styled with CSS of course. 
I have the PHP code prepared, but I'm not exactly sure where to place it. Currently I have it on it's own page and the html is pointing to it with "action", but when I test the page and submit the form it just goes to a blank page. Here's a sample of my HTML code.. and PHP code... The page can be seen here... http://wayhigh.we.bs/contact.html

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" class="form" id="form1">

  <p class="name">
    <input name="name" type="text"            class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name"  id="name" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback- input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  </p>


  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and PHP...

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['text'];
$from = 'From: J. Michaels'; 
$to = 'mailto:benjamminredden@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello from a visitor';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
/* Anything that goes in here is only performed if the form is submitted */
}

if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: depends on what you want the user to see after they press submit

Comment: @Dagon Presumably he wants them to see __Your message has been sent!__ from the PHP script.

Comment: You can include the PHP code within the HTML form, just put it before the `<form></form>`. After that try learning how to use PHP function ISSET.

Comment: Preferably, I'd like them to stay on that page, if possible; and have the data sent to an e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `name="submit"` to the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
```

Otherwise, `if ($_POST['submit'])` won't succeed.

Comment: This made the script work; not exactly the way I want it to, but it worked. However it didn't send me an e-mail. Could this because I'm developing locally using MAMP?

Comment: It could be. You probably need to put something in the PHP configuration to tell it where your SMTP server is. Sorry, but I'm not familiar with that part of configuring PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I added the `isset` in `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

**PHP** code before the HTML form

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['text'];
$from = 'From: J. Michaels'; 
$to = 'mailto:benjamminredden@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello from a visitor';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
/* Anything that goes in here is only performed if the form is submitted */
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
}
?>

<form method="post" action="index.php" class="form" id="form1">

  <p class="name">
    <input name="name" type="text"            class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name"  id="name" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback- input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  </p>


  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"  name="submit" />
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question to include the solution. It is confusing!